# gRPC java: Enable TLS encryption without using CA certificate

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, grpc, grpc-java

I've been working a while on getting gRPC to run with TLS. I have a working server which I confirm is running TLS by using Postman. I've been reading the docs namely here: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#java which states I can use:

```
        var credentials = TlsChannelCredentials.create();
        channel = Grpc.newChannelBuilderForAddress(hostName, port, credentials).build();

        return channel;
```

However it is throwing the exception:

`Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Which in turn bubbles up to:

`UNAVAILABLE: io exception Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0] io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]`

I can confirm that the Client request pops up and exchanges the Client Hello via Wireshark.

What I want to achieve is using TLS *only* as encryption. I do not care about the client side CA/trust store etc. Can anybody help or tell me what I'm doing wrong or if I am misunderstanding the docs?

Thank you all

Comment: You *do* care about the CA/trust store etc. There's not much point in carrying on an encrypted conversation with an attacker.

Comment: You are right of course, but this is within a a kubernetes environment so this kind of attack so in my case for the moment I do not actually care :)

Comment: So use plaintext. Don't implement an insecure solution, even temporarily. I tremble to think how many of these have made their way into production.

Comment: Without an encryption stream it still very listenable internally. Which is why I want the connection to simply agree through ALPN to encrypt it.

Comment: And without a proper certificate system it is not only 'still very listenable' but still very *impersonatable* internally, which is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TLS the client *has* to accept the server certificate before proceeding to the next step (negotiate the session key for encryption).

To enable that you can import the server's public certificate chain and supply it on the client side via `TlsChannelCredentials` 's `trustManager(File rootCerts)` method. You should be able to find enough pointers on the web to figure out how to do it.